# Question about $\mathfrak{g}$-module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am reading some notes on Lie algebras and they say something which I don't quite understand. Let $M$ and $N$ be two $\mathfrak{g}$-modules. The space of $\mathfrak{g}$-module homomorphism is denoted Hom$_{\mathfrak{g}}(M,N)$. When $M=N$ we write End$_{\mathfrak{g}}(M)$ for this space. Then they say that Hom$_{\mathfrak{g}}(M,N)$ is a subspace of Hom$_{\mathbb{C}}(M,N)$ and End$_{\mathfrak{g}}(M)$ is a subspace of End$_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$. Can someone explain why this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak g}(M,N)$ are the linear maps $\varphi$ from $M$ into $N$ such that$$(\forall X,Y\in M):\varphi\bigl([X,Y]\bigr)=\bigl[\varphi(X),\varphi(Y)\bigr].$$In particular, the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak g}(M,N)$ are linear maps, and therefore they are elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(M,N)$.

Comment: Thank you! Ok, so basically they're just some linear maps between vector spaces (over $\mathbb{C}$) satisfying some extra property, which clearly not every linear map from $M$ to $N$ will satisfy and so they're only a subspace.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.